# Shift + Tab not working in asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, tabs, shift

I am trying to allow navigation inside the gridview using tab for forward and shift+tab for reverse navigation. I was able to get tab working but just setting the tabindex property of cells but shift+tab does not do anything

Do I need to write key press code to make it work? If Yes what should be the key code for that?

Thanks,
Arshya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make tab+shift work using this code

```
function handleKeyDownEvent(elementRef, eventRef) {
    var charCode = (window.event) ? eventRef.keyCode : eventRef.which;

    // shift + tab arrow...
    if (eventRef.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 9) {

         var prevTabIndex = elementRef.tabIndex;

         if (prevTabIndex > 0)
              $('td[tabindex=' + prevTabIndex + ']').focus();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) is the list of key codes.